# Text-Align changes when changing width in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want my Text to be centered with a width of 40%. In my last example of code everything is perfect but the text appears to be like 10px under the `<p>` element.

Without the width 40%:

```
<p id="pname" style="text-align:center; color:white;overflow:hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;">
Some really long text in here
</p>
```

--> Text has a width of 40% but is not centered

With width 40%:

```
<p id="pname" style="text-align:center; width:40%;color:white;overflow:hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;">
Some really long text in here
</p>
```

--> Text appears to have a text-align:left

With display:inline-block:

```
<p id="pname" style="display:inline-block;text-align:center; width:40%;color:white;overflow:hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;">
Some really long text in here
</p>
```

-->  The text is aligned correctly and perfectly 40% width but the Text appears under the `<p>`

What am i missing? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To center a block level element in CSS, you have to add `margin:0 auto;` because `text-align:center` affects text and `inline` elements only.

```css
p {
  margin: 0 auto; /* center element horizontally */
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background:#666;
}

body { background:#000; }
```

```html
<p id="pname">Some really long text in here</p>
```