# WP theme footer text alignment

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to arrange the text in the site-info footer div in the Wordpress 2016 theme (child) to the centre of the div:

[image: div.site-info]

I've applied the following css, but cannot get the text to align in the middle of the div:

```
.site-info, .site-info a {
text-align: center;
```

}

I'm unsure whats causing this?  I've tried position:relative too but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: possible dupe of [text-align changes when changing width in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454883/text-align-changes-when-changing-width-in-html/35454933#35454933)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.site-info {
    text-align: center;
    display:block;
}
```

It seems .site-info is an `inline` element and its width is determined by the content inside it. By making it a `block` element, it will occupy the entire width of its parent and thus the text will be in  the middle as expected.

UPDATE from question author:

In the inbuilt Wordpress 2016 theme there was a different class that needed altering with CodeRomeos / Aziz comments:

```
.site-footer { display:block; }
```

Comment: this will make the link a block, covering the entire thing!!

Comment: @Aziz is correct.  it does!  I got it to work doing this though: `.site-footer {
    display:block;
}`

Comment: anchor tag is not block elements. so when we try to center them we have to choose  `anchor` by targeting `a` . That is it. Happy you did it.

Comment: @CodeRomeos yes you are right, however, the content is wrapped in `.site-info` which is not the anchor. see my revision

Comment: @Aziz you answer has been deleted?

Comment: @MrT yes, this answer by CodeRomeos is the better one. Mine is unnecessary and doesn't apply to your situation so I have deleted it :)

Comment: @Aziz OK. It turns out that when I did display:block on the .site-info class the hyperlinks (I have several now on the same line) they went full width each (meaning they were no longer on the same line).  I added the display:block on the previous div as per my answer below which did the trick for a 2016 child theme.

Comment: @Aziz - just realised I can update this answer - as you guys had the answer.  Thanks